# Elasticsearch doesn't recognize new nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10 nodes. All of them are connected to the cluster.
I want to add a new node with same data node configuration (in elasticsearch.yml) just changing the name.
But, I get an error that "failed to join".
How can i solve this ?
Thanks for answering

Comment: We must have more context to fix this, where do you deploy your cluster ? On cloud, managed service, on premise, which one?

Comment: I deploy on my linux machine with just one host